# Differentiate the Function: $y=x^{\cos\ x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=x^{\cos\ x}$

$\ln\ y = \cos(x)\ln\ x$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{1}{y}=\frac{-\sin(x)}{x}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{\cos x}(\frac{-\sin(x)}{x})$

Is my method and steps correct?

Comment: No, you should apply the product rule to differentiate a product ...

Comment: From line 2 to line 3, you used the product rule in a wrong way.

Comment: You need to apply the product rule of differntiation to the right hand side

Comment: Use the product rule on $cosxlnx$. You simply multiplied the derivative of $cosx$ and $lnx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$y={ x }^{ \cos { x }  }\\ \ln { y } =\cos { x } \ln { x } \\ \frac { d\left( \ln { y }  \right)  }{ dx } =\frac { d\left( \cos { x } \ln { x }  \right)  }{ dx } \\ \frac { 1 }{ y }\frac { dy }{ dx } =\frac { d\left( \cos { x }  \right)  }{ dx } \ln { x+\cos { x } \frac { d\left( \ln { x }  \right)  }{ dx }  } \\ \frac { 1 }{ y } \frac { dy }{ dx } =-\sin { x } \ln { x } +\frac { \cos { x }  }{ x } \\ \frac { dy }{ dx }={ x }^{ \cos { x }  }\left( -\sin { x } \ln { x } +\frac { \cos { x }  }{ x }  \right) $$

Comment: One question about the negative sign, does it matter if you put it between the ln ? For example $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{cos(x)}(\frac{cos(x)}{x}+lnx-sin(x))$

Comment: $\ln { x } -\sin { x } $ and $-\sin { x } \ln { x } $ are different things

Comment: @SunnyBlack Yes it matters, see Nemo's answer (last line) - what you wrote is incorrect interpretation of the answer.

Comment: Why? Since I am following the sequential order of the terms, when finding the derivatives.

Comment: It's the way you write it. $a-b$ is a subtraction, $a(-b)=-ab=-ba$ is a product. $2-3=-1$, but $2(-3)=-6$... when we write $ab$, this means $a\cdot b$: the multplication sign is implicit, it's not just putting the two letters one next to the other.

Comment: @Nemo Can I solve this problem using the above method? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371549/differentiate-the-function-y-log-2e-x-cos-pi-x/1371571#1371571

Comment: there is not special method i guess to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Not quite: $(uv)^\prime = u^\prime v +uv^\prime$, not $u^\prime v^\prime$. The derivative $\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x)\ln(x))$ is not $\cos^\prime(x)\ln^\prime(x)$.

Comment: So the answer should be $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{cos(x)}(\frac{cos(x)}{x}+lnx-sin(x))$?

Comment: In the parenthesis, $\frac{\cos x}{x}-\ln(x)\cdot\sin x$.

Comment: So the negative sign negates the entire product?

Comment: Yes: in a product, $a\times (-b) = (-b)\times a = -a\times b = -(a\times b)$.

Comment: Can you take a look at this problem? Can I solve it in the same way? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371549/differentiate-the-function-y-log-2e-x-cos-pi-x/1371571#1371571

Comment: I don't really see what you mean by "the same way." Additionally, you may want to either open a new question, or ask this question there.

Comment: What I meant was taking the logs of both sides of the equation. However, I now see that the formula I need to us is $\frac{d}{dx}(log_ax)=\frac{1}{xlna}\cdot f'(x)$ Correct?

Comment: Since $f$ only appears on the RHS, it cannot be correct as written... also, you really should consider asking other questions in a separate Math.SE thread: several different questions in the same is not really recommended not good practice.